# Trim nested lists within variable using `lapply` and `grepl`

Tags: r, lapply

I am working with scraped data, and am using a variable that is split into a nested list for multiple purposes. Here's what I want to do:

1. Look for items within the nested list that have an exact match with the string "Highlights"
2. Identify and remove all nested list items that contain a colon (`:`)
3. Identify and remove all nested list items with more than 30 characters
4. Re-order the list so "Highlight" is at the top
5. Wrap the list items that are not "Highlight" in HTML (with `<li>` before the nested list item, and `</li>`behind it).
6. Unlist, and add `<ul>` wrappers at the beginning and end of the string so the list is formatted for HTML

Here's an example:
**ORIGINAL TEXT**

```
[1] "Phthalate Free"
[2] "Paraben Free"
[3] "Sulfate Free"
[4] "Highlights"
[5] "Reduces Pores" 
[6] "The Peach Slices Shrink Pores Mask contains exfoliating willow bark, soothing hinoki cypress, hydrating rose, brightening citrus, clarifying cinnamon and other natural ingredients to help firm skin and reduce the appearance of pores. This natural cotton sheet mask will nourish and pamper your skin with the hydration it needs.
[7] "TCIN: 53659598"
[8] "UPC: 818000020054"
[9] "Item Number (DPCI): 037-14-1205"
```

**DESIRED TEXT BEFORE UNLISTING**

```
[1] "Highlights"
[2] "<li>Phthalate Free</li>"
[3] "<li>Paraben Free</li>"
[4] "<li>Sulfate Free</li>"
[5] "<li>Reduces Pores</li>"
```

**FINAL RESULT**
    [1] ""`<ul>`Highlights`<li>`Phthalate Free`</li><li>`Paraben Free`</li><li>`Sulfate Free`</li><li>`Reduces Pores`</li></ul>`"

I have some very ugly `lapply` functions that I am struggling with to make these transformations, step-by-step, but am hoping there is an elegant solution.

A bit more test data is available here:

```
dput(head(tgt$clean.text))
list(c("Phthalate Free", "Paraben Free", "Sulfate Free", "No Added Fragrance", 
"Highlights", "Made for Young Delicate Skin Types", "Mineral pressed powder foundation blends easily to give skin natural light to medium coverage", 
"Clinically Tested on Sensitive Skin", "Dermatologist Tested, Hypoallergenic, Fragrance-Free, Talc-Free", 
"NO - Talc, Fragrance, Parabens, Phthalates, Sulfates, Mineral oil or Propylene Glycol", 
"This pressed mineral powder foundation offers buildable, light to medium coverage with a unique sheer formula designed to conceal without appearing heavy or caked on.", 
"Health Facts: Sulfate-free, Talcum-free, butylparaben-free, formaldehyde donor-free, formaldehyde-free, hypoallergenic, mineral oil-free, no fragrance added, non-toxic, paraben-free, phthalate-free, propylparaben-free, sodium lauryl sulfate-free, nonylphenol ethoxylate free, propylparaben-free, aluminum-free", 
"Color Family: Beige", "Color Palette: Light Tones", "Product Form: Pressed Powder", 
"Suggested Age: 8 Years and Up", "Cosmetic Coverage: Medium", 
"Skin Tone: Medium", "Wellness Standard: Meets minimum requirements, no fragrance added, paraben-free, phthalate-free, sulfate-free", 
"Recommended Skin Type: Normal", "Beauty Purpose: Color correction", 
"Features: Blendable, Lightweight, Unscented, dermatologist tested", 
"TCIN: 53070801", "UPC: 039897626147", "Item Number (DPCI): 037-14-1089", 
"Phthalate Free", "A product that either carries an unqualified on-pack statement indicating that the product is free from phthalates, or carries an unqualified on-pack statement \"no phthalates,\" or A product which is never formulated with phthalates, as confirmed by the manufacturer.", 
"Paraben Free", "A product that either carries an unqualified on-pack statement indicating that the product is free from parabens, or carries an unqualified on-pack statement \"no parabens,\" or A product which is never formulated with parabens, as confirmed by the manufacturer.", 
"Sulfate Free", "A product that either makes an unqualified on-pack statement indicating that it does not contain sulfates (not added sulfates); or carries an unqualified on-pack statement \"no sulfates\" or \"sulfate-free\".", 
"No Added Fragrance", "A product that either makes an on-pack statement indicating that it does not contain synthetic fragrance, or carries an unqualified on-pack statement \"no fragrance\".", 
"If the item details above are not accurate or complete, we want to know about it. Report incorrect product info."
), c("Phthalate Free", "Paraben Free", "Sulfate Free", "Cruelty Free", 
"No Added Fragrance", "Highlights", "Reduces Pores", "Deep hydration", 
"Contains willow bark0.84 fl oz", "The Peach Slices Shrink Pores Mask contains exfoliating willow bark, soothing hinoki cypress, hydrating rose, brightening citrus, clarifying cinnamon and other natural ingredients to help firm skin and reduce the appearance of pores. This natural cotton sheet mask will nourish and pamper your skin with the hydration it needs. Say goodbye to your dead skin cells and hello to fresh, radiant skin with the Peach Slices Shrink Pores Mask\\!Scent: Fresh", 
"Health Facts: Sulfate-free, paraben-free, dye-free, aluminum-free, phthalate-free, no fragrance added", 
"Product Warning: Adult Use Only", "Product Form: Sheet", "Recommended Skin Type: Normal", 
"Beauty Purpose: Pore reduction", "Skin concern: Visible pores", 
"Sustainability Claims: Cruelty-free", "TCIN: 53659598", "UPC: 818000020054", 
"Item Number (DPCI): 037-14-1205", "Healthcare Disclaimer: Content on this site is for reference purposes only.  Target does not represent or warrant that the nutrition, ingredient, allergen and other product information on our Web or Mobile sites are accurate or complete, since this information comes from the product manufacturers.  On occasion, manufacturers may improve or change their product formulas and update their labels.  We recommend that you do not rely solely on the information presented on our Web or Mobile sites and that you review the product's label or contact the manufacturer directly if you have specific product concerns or questions.  If you have specific healthcare concerns or questions about the products displayed, please contact your licensed healthcare professional for advice or answers.", 
"Phthalate Free", "A product that either carries an unqualified on-pack statement indicating that the product is free from phthalates, or carries an unqualified on-pack statement \"no phthalates,\" or A product which is never formulated with phthalates, as confirmed by the manufacturer.", 
"Paraben Free", "A product that either carries an unqualified on-pack statement indicating that the product is free from parabens, or carries an unqualified on-pack statement \"no parabens,\" or A product which is never formulated with parabens, as confirmed by the manufacturer.", 
"Sulfate Free", "A product that either makes an unqualified on-pack statement indicating that it does not contain sulfates (not added sulfates); or carries an unqualified on-pack statement \"no sulfates\" or \"sulfate-free\".", 
"Cruelty Free", "A product has an independent third-party certification on pack or unqualified on-pack marketing claim relating to being cruelty-free and/or not tested on animals.", 
"No Added Fragrance", "A product that either makes an on-pack statement indicating that it does not contain synthetic fragrance, or carries an unqualified on-pack statement \"no fragrance\".", 
"If the item details above are not accurate or complete, we want to know about it. Report incorrect product info."
), c("Highlights", "Soft, refreshing texture", "For sensitive skin", 
"La Roche-Posay Toleriane Riche Soothing Protective Face Cream for Dry, sensitive and very sensitive skin. Formulated with Shea Butter to nourish and replenish skin's surface with lipids, and with La Roche-Posay Thermal Water to help soothe skin. This face cream contains a limited number of ingredients designed with the tolerance of sensitive skin in mind.\n\nHow to Use: Use daily. After mild cleansing, apply this moisturizer to the face and neck morning and evening.", 
"Scent: Unscented", "Health Facts: Paraben-free, no fragrance added", 
"Product Form: Cream", "Recommended Skin Type: Dry, normal, sensitive, mature", 
"Beauty Purpose: Deep hydration, moisturizing, spot treatment", 
"Skin concern: Dark spots, dry skin, fine lines", "Features: Dermatologist tested", 
"TCIN: 14225616", "UPC: 3433422405295", "Item Number (DPCI): 037-14-0282", 
"Healthcare Disclaimer: Content on this site is for reference purposes only.  Target does not represent or warrant that the nutrition, ingredient, allergen and other product information on our Web or Mobile sites are accurate or complete, since this information comes from the product manufacturers.  On occasion, manufacturers may improve or change their product formulas and update their labels.  We recommend that you do not rely solely on the information presented on our Web or Mobile sites and that you review the product's label or contact the manufacturer directly if you have specific product concerns or questions.  If you have specific healthcare concerns or questions about the products displayed, please contact your licensed healthcare professional for advice or answers.", 
"If the item details above are not accurate or complete, we want to know about it. Report incorrect product info."
), c("Highlights", "Daily anti-aging primer with sunscreen protection.", 
"For everyday use. Matte finish texture.", "Primer with sunscreen, provides blurring-effect on skin.", 
"For daily use with or without makeup", "La Roche-Posay Anthelios Daily Anti-Aging Face Primer with sunscreen SPF 50 instantly provides a visible blurring-effect on signs of aging: fine lines, wrinkles and pores. For everyday use. Matte finish texture. The Anti-Aging Face Primer with Sunscreen provides a blurring-effect on skin. For daily use with or without makeup.\n\nHow to Use: Apply each morning to clean face and neck; 15 minutes before sun exposure. Use as last step in skincare routine.", 
"Scent: Unscented", "Health Facts: Noncomedogenic, no fragrance added, paraben-free", 
"Product Form: Cream", "SPF: 50", "Recommended Skin Type: Normal", 
"Beauty Purpose: Sun protection, anti-aging, smoothing, pore reduction, color correction, brightening", 
"Skin concern: Aging, skin health, sun protection, sensitive skin", 
"TCIN: 14225596", "UPC: 883140020950", "Item Number (DPCI): 037-14-0098", 
"Healthcare Disclaimer: Content on this site is for reference purposes only.  Target does not represent or warrant that the nutrition, ingredient, allergen and other product information on our Web or Mobile sites are accurate or complete, since this information comes from the product manufacturers.  On occasion, manufacturers may improve or change their product formulas and update their labels.  We recommend that you do not rely solely on the information presented on our Web or Mobile sites and that you review the product's label or contact the manufacturer directly if you have specific product concerns or questions.  If you have specific healthcare concerns or questions about the products displayed, please contact your licensed healthcare professional for advice or answers.", 
"If the item details above are not accurate or complete, we want to know about it. Report incorrect product info."
), c("Highlights", "Hydromoist balancing cream is ideal for dry and sensitive skin", 
"Contains Bio Science Complex technology that promotes fast and deep absorption, delivering active components to skin", 
"Strengthens skin's protective layer", "Oil-free and non-sticky cream provides long-lasting hydration", 
"This Hydromoist Balancing Cream from Derma Dr.", "Lab helps to restore the natural balance in your skin. The nutrient-rich cream provides moisture to your skin, while controlling the skin's oil-water balance and providing a long-lasting moisture benefits year-round, which is particularly necessary for those in dry and arid climates. The balancing cream also helps to avoid loss of moisture by reinforcing the skin's protective shield, helping you retain a healthy-looking glow.", 
"Scent: Fresh", "Product Form: Cream", "Recommended Skin Type: Combination, dry, normal, sensitive", 
"Beauty Purpose: Anti-aging, moisturizing, skin tone improvement, fine line reduction, skin texture improvement", 
"Skin concern: Aging, basic care, dry skin, fine lines", "Features: Dermatologist tested", 
"TCIN: 50580868", "UPC: 8809112139903", "Item Number (DPCI): 037-14-0609", 
"Healthcare Disclaimer: Content on this site is for reference purposes only.  Target does not represent or warrant that the nutrition, ingredient, allergen and other product information on our Web or Mobile sites are accurate or complete, since this information comes from the product manufacturers.  On occasion, manufacturers may improve or change their product formulas and update their labels.  We recommend that you do not rely solely on the information presented on our Web or Mobile sites and that you review the product's label or contact the manufacturer directly if you have specific product concerns or questions.  If you have specific healthcare concerns or questions about the products displayed, please contact your licensed healthcare professional for advice or answers.", 
"If the item details above are not accurate or complete, we want to know about it. Report incorrect product info."
), c("Highlights", "Moisturizer with glycerin replenishes and retains moisture for smooth skin", 
"Loaded with vitamins B2 and E that soothe and heal skin", "Non-greasy formula dries quickly", 
"Fragrance-free moisturizer with natural ingredients is great for those with allergies or sensitivities to smells", 
"Treat dry skin in a natural way with Moisturizing Skin Cream from Yu-Be. This fast-absorbing moisturizer is loaded with highly concentrated plant-based glycerin and vitamins B2 and E that replenish and retain moisture while nourishing and healing skin, leaving it smooth and velvety soft. The non-greasy formula also contains camphor that soothes dry and patchy skin, making it effective for use anywhere on the body including the face and lips.", 
"Scent: Unscented", "Suggested Age: All Ages", "Recommended Skin Type: Dry", 
"Beauty Purpose: Moisturizing", "TCIN: 51251940", "UPC: 850353000338", 
"Item Number (DPCI): 037-14-0716", "If the item details above are not accurate or complete, we want to know about it. Report incorrect product info."
))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When working with lists in base R lapply is one of the most common options.  You can also check out `purrr` [here](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/) that does a good job of applying functions to a list.  I've tried breaking down your problem with just `lapply` but I may come back later and give the `purrr` approach

```
df <- df[grepl("Highlights",df)] # Look for items within the nested list that have an exact match with the string "Highlights"
df <- lapply(df,function(x) x[!grepl(":",x)]) # Identify and remove all nested list items that contain a colon (:)
df <- lapply(df,function(x) x[!nchar(x)>30]) # Identify and remove all nested list items with more than 30 characters
df <- lapply(df,function(x) x[!grepl("Highlights",x)]) # Remove highlight for now to add to front later
df <- lapply(df,function(x) x[!duplicated(x)]) # Remove any duplicates
df <- lapply(df,function(x) gsub("^(.*)$","<li>\\1</li>",x)) # add in the wrappers
df <- lapply(df,function(x) append(x,"Highlights", after = 0)) # add back in the highlights in first position
df <- lapply(df,function(x) paste0(x,collapse = "")) # collapse to single string
df <- lapply(df,function(x) paste0("<ul>",x,"</ul>")) #  add in the final wrappers
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I'm playing around with another scenario, which would be to delete everything that comes in the list before "Highlights." I know that an `lapply` function with `match("Highlights",x)` would return the position, but I can't figure out how to all list items prior to (and including) that position. If you have any thoughts on that too, would help - I can also modify my Q.

Comment: `lapply(df,function(x) x[which(x == "Highlights"):length(x)])` will delete everything before "Highlights"

Answer (score 0):

If we call your list above `search.list`, then does this do what you want:

```
> sapply(search.list, function(x) {
+   # Look for items within the nested list that have an exact match with the string "Highlights"
+   highlights <- which(x == "Highlights")
+   
+   # Identify and remove all nested list items that contain a colon (:)
+   x <- x[-grep(":", x)]
+   
+   # Identify and remove all nested list items with more than 30 characters
+   x <- x[nchar(x) <= 30]
+   
+   # Re-order the list so "Highlight" is at the top
+   x <- c("Highlights", x[-highlights])
+   x <- x[!duplicated(x)]
+   
+   # Wrap the list items that are not "Highlight" in HTML (with <li> before the nested list item, and </li>behind it).
+   x[-1] <- paste("<li>", x[-1], "</li>")
+   
+   # Unlist, and add <ul> wrappers at the beginning and end of the string so the list is formatted for HTML
+   x <- paste(x, collapse = " ")
+   paste("<ul>", x, "</ul>")
+ })
[1] "<ul> Highlights <li> Phthalate Free </li> <li> Paraben Free </li> <li> Sulfate Free </li> <li> No Added Fragrance </li> </ul>"                                                                                                                     
[2] "<ul> Highlights <li> Phthalate Free </li> <li> Paraben Free </li> <li> Sulfate Free </li> <li> Cruelty Free </li> <li> No Added Fragrance </li> <li> Reduces Pores </li> <li> Deep hydration </li> <li> Contains willow bark0.84 fl oz </li> </ul>"
[3] "<ul> Highlights <li> Soft, refreshing texture </li> <li> For sensitive skin </li> </ul>"                                                                                                                                                           
[4] "<ul> Highlights </ul>"                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
[5] "<ul> Highlights </ul>"                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
[6] "<ul> Highlights </ul>"
```